# JsonConverter игнорируется в .NET7 (F#)

Tags: .net, asp.net, сериализация, f#, .net-7

Проблема возникла после миграции на .NET 7. В предыдущих версиях (и 5 и 6) аттрибут не игнорировался, и проблем с сериализацией не возникало.

Есть кастомный JSON конвертер:

```
type RouteCheckConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter<RouteCheckResponse>()

    override _.Read(reader, _, _): RouteCheckResponse =
        match reader.GetInt32() with 
        | 200 -> RouteOk
        | 301 -> RouteRedirect
        | 404 -> RouteNotFound
        | _ -> failwithf "Unknown route check response"

    override _.Write (writer, r, _): unit =
        match r with
        | RouteOk -> writer.WriteNumberValue 200
        | RouteRedirect -> writer.WriteNumberValue 301
        | RouteNotFound -> writer.WriteNumberValue 404
```

RouteCheckResponse - это discriminated union:

```
type RouteCheckResponse = | RouteOk | RouteRedirect | RouteNotFound
```

Вот класс, использующий конвертер:

```
type RouteCheckResultDTO = {
    page: ProductPageDTO option
    redirectTo: string option
    [<JsonConverter(typeof<RouteCheckConverter>)>] 
    response: RouteCheckResponse
}
```

Когда приложение пытается вернуть DTO, возникает исключение:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.NotSupportedException: F# discriminated union serialization is not supported. Consider authoring a custom converter for the type.
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.FSharpTypeConverterFactory.CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverterFactory.GetConverterInternal(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetConverterForType(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean resolveJsonConverterAttribute)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreateJsonTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoNoCaching(Type type)
         at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Boolean resolveIfMutable)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.Configure()
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.InitializePropertyCache()
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.Configure()
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureLocked|143_0()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

(и т.д.), то есть конвертация не производится.

Сериалтзация не вызывается явно и применяется автоматически, когда контроллер возвращает DTO в ответ на REST-запрос. Почему конвертер перестал работать? Это баг или мне необходимоо явно указать какие-то настройки? Если да, то где именно?

Comment: Попробуйте явно добавить конвертер в `JsonSerializerOptions`, почему это раньше работало, а сейчас нет хз